# PHP fopen doesn't find existing file

Tags: php, fopen

I'm currently writting a login-system with PHP, for that I need to read the files with some user-information in it.
But after changing the folder system, PHP fopen doesn't read the files anymore.

Both the users.php and userinf.csv files are in the samle folder.

I allready tried to change the filepath, hard-coded the filepath , recreated the file. All of which file.

```
//Read file
$fp = fopen("userinf.csv", "r");
if(!$fp)
{
    echo "File couldn't be read";
    return false;
}
```

Before changing the file system, it worked. But now I am geting the error:
Warning: fopen(userinf.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in FILEPATH on line 45

Comment: When you execute the `getcwd()` function, do you get the right directory?

Comment: That's it! It stays in the folder-location of my index.php instead of the users.php
Thank you!

Comment: @Tim Doesn't matter where your file located.. The matter is the location where you are calling the file. Good Job #Koen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the fread function without any reference it could fail. I always say that you need to check your path first with `getcwd()`

```
<?php
echo getcwd(); //Current Working Directory
?>
```

Comment: This isn't really the answer, it should be something like `fopen(dirname(__FILE__). ' /userinf.csv', 'r')`

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths, always. It removes any ambiguity. Using a relative path may change based on where your script is located, among other things, depending on your system.

```
$fp = fopen("/home/somewhere/blah/userinf.csv", "r");
```

You can always use a variable for the path as well:

```
// Somewhere in your code
define('ROOT_PATH', "/home/somewhere/blah");

// In the implementation
$fp = fopen(ROOT_PATH . "/userinf.csv", "r");
```

Comment: Using relative paths for final location based on location of script can be desirable sometimes.